# How can I use the native pdf reader in windows 8 metro app?

Tags: windows, pdf, windows-runtime

I want to make a pdfreader with the native pdf reader in Windows 8 (consumerpreview version). I find a dll (Microsoft.LightSwitch.Design.Extensions.Reader) Is this the dll that I can use ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not likely the pdf library is exposed in any way. An [earlier question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/6f27a046-842e-4c46-aee0-e4c83cf4faf2) on MSDN forums suggested opening a pdf file with the default program associated with it like this:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFile file =
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.
        Package.Current.InstalledLocation
            .GetFileAsync(@"Images\test.pdf");
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchDefaultProgramForFile(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.LightSwitch.Design.Extensions.Reader is not native, it's a WinRT library, its PE header reveals its real identity.

You can use the freeware PDF Reader for Windows 8, or its DLL for your development.

http://www.pdfeight.com

Comment: Do PDFEight provide DLL for developers? I could not find any DLL option from them.