# PDF viewer from inside the winJS application

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

### PDF viewer from inside the winJS application

Hi i am working on a winJS application.I need to open a PDF file from inside the application without using native pdf launcher.

Comment: In past I have tried but did not find good quality solution that is free. there are pdf viewer libs available but cost > 1k for licensing.

Comment: you can try PDFRasteri​zer from tallcomponents.com - also see syncfusion.com essential studio - note I have not used their lib. if you bing, you will find some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) a try but with the craziness that is PDF, there's a high likelyhood you'll have rendering problems with some files.

Otherwise you'll need a native component, for which you'll find lots of proposals in these questions:

- [Rendering PDF in Window 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392465/rendering-pdf-in-window-8)
- [Is there an API for the built-in Windows 8 "Modern reader" PDF Viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714500/is-there-an-api-for-the-built-in-windows-8-modern-reader-pdf-viewer)
- [Embeded Acrobat Reader in Windows 8 Store Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368140/embeded-acrobat-reader-in-windows-8-store-application)
- [PDF, DOC Library on Windows 8 (RT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347921/pdf-doc-library-on-windows-8-rt)
- [How can I use the native pdf reader in windows 8 metro app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562946/how-can-i-use-the-native-pdf-reader-in-windows-8-metro-app)

We use [DynaPDF](http://www.dynaforms.com/) in our app.

Comment: DynaPDF support winJS?

Comment: We added a simple C++ component that wraps the library so we can use it from WinJS. But it's very straightforward as it just needs to accept a path to a PDF file and render the first page into a file. If you need more than simple rendering, the whole thing becomes much more complex and needing a C++ component wrapper is probably the least of your worries ;)

Comment: can i get sample code or any reference link?

Comment: I'll check with my boss if it would be ok to publish the code

Comment: ok..any site refernce?

Comment: You can download a basic version of DynaPDF from their site and have a look at the headers. For C++ component development and accessing it from JavaScript see (among others): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441569.aspx

Comment: can i get a sample code?